# Добавление значения со строковым индексом в массив

Tags: php

Имеется массив `array()`. Как программно добавить в него `use = 123qwerty` и `like  = yes1`, т.е. чтобы массив выглядел так: `array("use" => "123qwerty", "like" => "yes1")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//так
$arr['use'] = '123qwerty';
$arr['like'] = 'yes1';
//или так
$arr2=array('use' => '123qwerty', 'like' => 'yes1');
```